# HybridAuth has stopped working with FaceBook

Tags: social-network, users

Before the weekend, I successfully set up the [HybridAuth](http://drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module. Upon returning to this project this week (July 1), Facebook logins no longer seem to respond.

Watchdog logs contained numerous of the following lines

```
Exception: Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id. in Hybrid_Auth::initialize() (line 147 of xxxxxxxx/public_html/sites/all/libraries/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php).
```

[image]

Now I have checked the FB AppID and AppSecret. They are correct.

Permission is set as follows....

[image]

Sand box is off

[image]

I'm using the latest library from HybridAuth. I've clone it using git

Comment: Please report bugs in issue queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the issue already submitted in drupal.org https://drupal.org/node/1860618 . Especially check this [comment](https://drupal.org/comment/7291390#comment-7291390). You have to use latest 7.x-2.x-dev release.